# Saving text from Kendo Editor to database

Tags: save, kendo-editor

I have a Kendo Editor which is defined as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
                    .Name("myEditor")
                    .Tag("div")
                    .Tools(tools => tools
                            .Clear()
                            .Bold()
                            .Italic()
                            .Underline()
                            .Strikethrough()
                            .JustifyCenter().JustifyFull().JustifyLeft().JustifyRight()
                            .CreateLink().Unlink().TableEditing().FontColor().BackColor())
                     .Value(@<text>
                                Hello Kendo Editor <some text with html tags here>
                        </text>)
                )
```

Then I have two buttons that show up only for the admins - Save and Edit, and they are defined as below -

```
<button type="button" id="btnedit">Edit</button>
 <input type="submit" name="btnSave"  id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

There are other two submit buttons on the form like below -

```
<input type="submit" name="btnAgree"  id="btnAgree"  value="Agree" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="submit" name="btnDisagree" id="btnDisagree" value="Disagree" class="btn btn-default" />
```

And the form handles the submit of Agree and Disagree buttons by using the BeginForm("ActionMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post) like below -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
```

Now I want that, when an admin user comes in and makes changes to the Editor text and hits 'Save' button, I want the text of the editor to get saved in database. I can handle the saving part. I just want to know, how can I get the text from the Kendo Editor and send the text value to the action method in the controller.

I tried the solution provided in this thread here - http://www.telerik.com/forums/save-changes-to-and-print-content-of-editor-in-mvc

So, using the solution here I added an action method with the string argument name similar to the Editor name like below -

```
public ActionResult Save(string myEditor) {

// TO DO: Save the text to the database

 }
```

When I run my application, and hit 'Save' button, I get the below error -

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Invalid navigation The resource you are looking for
>   has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

It does not hit the 'Save' Action method. How can I get that working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what i do is the following (sorry already for the late response)

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    var form = $(this);

    // for each editor in the form
    form.find("[data-role=editor]").each(function () {
        var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");

        // ... add value of the editor to a hidden input
        $("#Description").val(editor.value());
    });


    $.post(saveOrUpdateEditor, $('#contentEditorKendo').serialize(),
        function (data) {

        });
});
```

also be sure to wrap the editor in a form whilst doing this
If you have more questions, please reach out

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an `AJAX` call in order to send the contents of `myEditor`?

You will need to change the `<input>` `type` attribute to just `button` so it is not treated as a submit and hook up an `onclick` event handler:

```
<input type="button" name="btnSave"  id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save()" />
```

Then hook up the associated Javascript function which will handle your AJAX call:

```
function save() {
    var enteredText = $("#myEditor").data("kendoEditor").value();
    alert(editor.value());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'yourController\Save',
        data: { "myEditor": JSON.stringify(enteredText) },
        success: function (response) {
            // handle a response following database operations
        },
    });
});
```

And don't forget to decorate your controller method with the relevant request method (in this case `POST`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string myEditor) {
    // TO DO: Save the text to the database
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandman for your answer. I tried the above approach, but I am getting Javascript error when it tries to get the value from Kendo Editor.   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Ensure you are accessing the [existing instance](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/editor/overview#existing-instances) after your MVC declaration.